# Jquery .removeAttr and .addClass on android

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I am making a mobile-ready site accessible and am having an issue getting the simple jquery function to run. I'm a bit of a beginner at it but have used simple functions like this in a lot of projects without hitch. This is my first attempt at a mobile-ready site.

Test page: http://arrowoodphotography.com/spaces/test.html

I've tried (document).ready and the below. This works w/o a problem on desktops but not on mobile devices.

I need to remove the attributes so I can use the mobile stylesheet to size the slideshow Object. I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I do.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){ 
    $("object").removeAttr("height");
    $("object").removeAttr("width");
    $("object").addClass("objectSize");
}); 
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `.css('height','auto')` and see if that does it?

Comment: Thanks for the response but the issue is that the jquery is not running, not the specific function. I am new to mobile so maybe it is a way I'm calling jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where I was trying to addclass and remove a class which contained a box-shadow property.

```
.requiredfocus
{
 box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF2A2A;  
}
```

It seemed to work everywhere except on an android browser, after digging around a bit I realized Mozilla and Webkit still require their respective -moz- and -webkit- prefixes. Hence what worked for me was something like this.

```
.requiredfocus
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF2A2A;
 box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF2A2A;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #FF2A2A;
}
```

Hope this helps.